# Function not rerunning query in cursor

Tags: postgresql, database-cursor

I have a cursor that runs through a number of records. For each row in the return, I need to check for it's existence in the return from another function. My problem is that, even with the functions being set to `VOLATILE`, the function does not seem to be rerun for each row in the cursor.

How can I get the function to rerun in order to get the updated information?

```sql
-- Cursor declaration
-- returns a list of users that are duplicated in the staging table.
-- _cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * from duplicated_records($1);


-- Cursor loop
FOR _record IN _cursor
    LOOP

      IF exists(SELECT id FROM non_matching_rows($1) WHERE id = _record.id) THEN
        WITH
          ins_users AS (
            INSERT INTO schema1.users (title, forename, surname)
              VALUES (_record.title, _record.first_name, _record.last_name)
              RETURNING user_id
          )
        UPDATE schema2.users c
        SET user_id = i.user_id
          FROM ins_users i
          WHERE c.id = _record.id;

      END IF;

    END LOOP;
```

I have tried both the above and `IF _record.id IN(SELECT id from non_matching_rows($1))` both giving same result. It seems to run `non_matching_rows()` only once. It seems this way because `non_matching_row()` loops through records that do not match and inserts according to pre-defined rules. There is a catch all condition that as long as the first or last name match, the records are inserted. With that insertion, they will match any future record and not be inserted, hence why I need it to run again for each row in the cursor. `non_matching_rows()` returns a list of the records from schema1 that do not meet preset matching rules. If a record in the cursor does not match, then it is inserted in the DB. If the next record matches, it should ***not*** be in the function return. But since the `non_matching_records()` is only being run the first time, matching rows are returning as not matched.

Comment: Please include sample data and expected results - as text, no images. Also include at least _cursor and result of your function non_matching_rows. I am not sure what the EXIT statement does within a cursor for loop, but should be removed, that is automatically handled by the FOR...Loop construct. Your contention  "But since the non_matching_records() is only being run the first time" seems to be a conclusion without supporting evidence.

Comment: @Belayer, I have updated the question and hopefully have addresses your comments. The sample data and expected results would be a simple list of non matching users.